# PHP - Simple HTML DOM: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object error

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I've been trying to fix this error for the longest time now, and I just can't seem to fix it.

I'm trying to get an article image, url, and url title. For some reason I keep getting the above error for this code:

```
<?php
$html = file_get_html("http://articlesite.com/");
if($html){
foreach ($html->find('.index_item a img') as $div) {
$articlePoster = $div->src;
$grabURL = $html->find('.index_item a');
/*Error Here -->*/$articleURL = $grabURL->href;
/*And Here -->*/$rawTitle = $grabURL->title;

echo '<div class="articleFrame"><a href="'.$articleURL.'"><img src="'.$articlePoster.'" width="125" height="186"/><br><p class="title">'.$rawTitle.'</p></a></div>';

}
}else{
echo '<h1>'."Sorry.".'</h1>';
}
?>
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: `var_dump($grabURL)`?

Comment: @Passerby `array(12) { [0]=> object(simple_html_dom_node)#271 (9) { ["nodetype"]=> int(1) ["tag"]=> string(1) "a" ["attr"]=> array(2) { ["href"]=> string(68) "http://articlesite.com/myarticle" ["title"]=> string(57) "Title of my article" } ["children"]=> array(2) { [0]=> object(simple_html_dom_node)#272 (9) { ` and then it goes on for hundreds of lines...

Comment: Now that you know `$grabURL` is _NOT_ an object :)

Answer (score 0):

`$html->find('xxxxx')` returns an array, so you need to iterate through it -- i.e.

```
foreach ($html->find('.index_item a img') as $div) {
    $articlePoster = $div->src;
    foreach ($html->find('.index_item a') as $grabURL) {
        $articleURL = $grabURL->href;
        $rawTitle = $grabURL->title;
    (etc.)
```